# Auto Sliding with the need of next,prev options

Tags: jquery, css, html

I could move the slides by clicking next and previous buttons. I just like to include an auto sliding view too. I need two functionality to work upon: auto sliding and also by clicking next,previous buttons. Is there possibility to add both the functionality in the code below.

Could anyone suggest me..Many Thanks

JS Fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gansai/axtvoatc/1/
```

sample.html

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cslide.js"></script>   
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cslide-slides").cslide();
    });
   </script>    

   <style type="text/css">    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
    #main { padding:0px 0; margin-left:0px; }
    .container { border: 1px solid green; margin: 0 auto; padding: 13px; width: 1090px; }
    .cslide-slides-master { overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 60px; }
    .cslide-slides-master:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
    .cslide-slides-container { visibility: hidden; }
    .cslide-slide { float: left; padding: 0px; border: solid 0px #38678f; background-color: none; }
    .cslide-slide h2, .cslide-slide p { color: #fff; }

    .cslide-prev-next { margin-bottom: 0px; display: none; text-align: right; -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; 
                        -khtml-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; }

    .cslide-prev, .cslide-next { display:inline-block; background:none; color:#fff; padding:0px 0px; border-bottom:solid 0px #38678f; cursor:pointer; }
    .cslide-prev:hover, .cslide-next:hover { background:#38678f; }
    .cslide-prev.cslide-disabled:hover,.cslide-next.cslide-disabled:hover { background: #b8b8b8; }
   </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main">                     
     <div class="container">
      <section id="cslide-slides" class="cslide-slides-master clearfix">
        <div class="cslide-slides-container clearfix">

         <!--Slide1-->
         <div class="cslide-slide">
                                  <div style="background:#c8c8c8;border-bottom-left-radius:10px;border-top-left-radius:10px;float:left;height:231px;margin:18px 0;padding:105px 6px;width:29px;"><img class="cslide-prev" src="<?php echo $OUTPUT->pix_url('left_icon', 'theme'); ?>" alt="colour"/></div>

                                  <div style="float:left;width:200px;height:273px;border:0px solid red;margin-left:6px;width:322px;border:1px solid red;">Content goes here </div>
                                  <div style="float:left;width:200px;height:273px;border:0px solid red;margin-left:6px;width:322px;border:1px solid red;">Content goes here </div>
                                  <div style="float:left;width:200px;height:273px;border:0px solid red;margin-left:6px;width:322px;border:1px solid red;">Content goes here </div>

                                  <div style="background:#c8c8c8;border-bottom-right-radius:10px;border-top-right-radius:10px;float:left;height:227px;margin:22px 5px;padding:99px 4px;width:29px;"><img class="cslide-next" src="<?php echo $OUTPUT->pix_url('right_icon', 'theme'); ?>" alt="colour"/></div>
         </div>
         <!--Slide1-->

         <!--Slide2-->
         <div class="cslide-slide">
                                  <div style="background:#c8c8c8;border-bottom-left-radius:10px;border-top-left-radius:10px;float:left;height:231px;margin:18px 0;padding:105px 6px;width:29px;"><img class="cslide-prev" src="<?php echo $OUTPUT->pix_url('left_icon', 'theme'); ?>" alt="colour"/></div>

                                  <div style="float:left;width:200px;height:273px;border:0px solid red;margin-left:6px;width:322px;border:1px solid red;">Content goes here </div>
                                  <div style="float:left;width:200px;height:273px;border:0px solid red;margin-left:6px;width:322px;border:1px solid red;">Content goes here </div>
                                  <div style="float:left;width:200px;height:273px;border:0px solid red;margin-left:6px;width:322px;border:1px solid red;">Content goes here </div>

                                  <div style="background:#c8c8c8;border-bottom-right-radius:10px;border-top-right-radius:10px;float:left;height:227px;margin:22px 5px;padding:99px 4px;width:29px;"><img class="cslide-next" src="<?php echo $OUTPUT->pix_url('right_icon', 'theme'); ?>" alt="colour"/></div>
         </div>
         <!--Slide2-->


        </div> <!--cslide-slides-container clearfix-->
      </section> 
     </div> <!--container-->            
    </div> <!--main-->
  </body>
</html>
```

jquery.cslide.js

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.cslide = function() {

        this.each(function() {

            var slidesContainerId = "#"+($(this).attr("id"));

            var len = $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide").size();     // get number of slides
            var slidesContainerWidth = len*100+"%";                     // get width of the slide container
            var slideWidth = (100/len)+"%";                             // get width of the slides

            // set slide container width
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container").css({
                width : slidesContainerWidth,
                visibility : "visible"
            });

            // set slide width
            $(".cslide-slide").css({
                width : slideWidth
            });

            // add correct classes to first and last slide
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container .cslide-slide").last().addClass("cslide-last");
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container .cslide-slide").first().addClass("cslide-first cslide-active");

            // initially disable the previous arrow cuz we start on the first slide
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").addClass("cslide-disabled");

            // if first slide is last slide, hide the prev-next navigation
            if (!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active.cslide-first").hasClass("cslide-last")) {           
                $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev-next").css({
                    display : "block"
                });
            }

            // handle the next clicking functionality
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-next").click(function(){
                var i = $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").index();
                var n = i+1;
                var slideLeft = "-"+n*100+"%";
                if (!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-last")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").removeClass("cslide-active").next(".cslide-slide").addClass("cslide-active");
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container").animate({
                        marginLeft : slideLeft
                    },250);
                    if ($(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-last")) {
                        $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-next").addClass("cslide-disabled");
                    }
                }
                if ((!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-first")) && $(".cslide-prev").hasClass("cslide-disabled")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").removeClass("cslide-disabled");
                }
            });

            // handle the prev clicking functionality
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").click(function(){
                var i = $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").index();
                var n = i-1;
                var slideRight = "-"+n*100+"%";
                if (!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-first")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").removeClass("cslide-active").prev(".cslide-slide").addClass("cslide-active");
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container").animate({
                        marginLeft : slideRight
                    },250);
                    if ($(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-first")) {
                        $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").addClass("cslide-disabled");
                    }
                }
                if ((!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-last")) && $(".cslide-next").hasClass("cslide-disabled")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-next").removeClass("cslide-disabled");
                }
            });



        });

        // return this for chainability
        return this;

    }

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that functionality by using `setInterval() method.`

For example move the code of `.click function` for next slide into a function, and pass the  `slidesContainerId`

And inside your `this.each` function , **after** initializing the common variables, you can use:

```
setInterval(function(){
  slideNext(slidesContainerId);
 },1000);
```

and this 1000 value can be set as a parameter for your library.
For an instance, check it out
 http://jsfiddle.net/axtvoatc/2/

Hope this helps..

Comment: :: Thank You for your help. The functionality isn't circulating from first slide to second slide. It should continuously repeat

Comment: Could anyone suggest me